# return a class containing generic List

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I'm trying to construct a class in c# (5.0) that I can use as a base class and it contains a List, but List could be 2 different types.  I want to do the following:

```
public class BaseC
{
    string header { get; set; }
    List<object> recs  { get; set; }
}

public class derive1: BaseC
{
    List<myclassA> recs;
}

public class derive2: BaseC
{
    List<myclassB> recs;
}
```

and importantly what I want to do is return the derived classes from a method in another class:

```
public BaseC PopulateMyDerivedClass()
{
    BaseC b = new BaseC();
    b.header = "stuff";
    b.recs =  FileHelperEngine<myclassB> fhe.ReadStringAsList(x);
}
```

the main point is that method `PopulateMyDerivedClass` really does the exact same thing for both `derive1` and `derive2`, just that it returns a different type of list.

I think I need generics.  But is that at the base class level and also is `PopulateMyDerivedClass` then supposed to return a generic?  I think that perhaps I am not dealing with polymorhpism, but as you can guess I am new to generics, so struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the feeling that your code design could use some rethinking. For one, typically when we talk about "polymorphism", we are usually talking about polymorphic *behaviors* (methods), rather than members. I think you might want to consider two classes that implement an interface that does all the things you want each class to do (parses data into its own type of list and acts on it as you need it to).

Nevertheless, without getting way into the details of your code, I think something like this might be what you were trying to achieve:

```
public class BaseC<T>
{
    string header { get; set; }
    public List<T> recs {get;set;}
}
```

and

```
public BaseC<T> PopulateClass<T>()
{
    var b = new BaseC<T>();
    b.recs = new List<T>();
    T first = (T)Convert.ChangeType("1", typeof(T));
    b.recs.Add(first);
    return b;
}
```

And to check our sanity:

```
BaseC<String> d1 = PopulateClass<String>();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(d1.recs.First().ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(d1.recs.First().GetType().ToString());
BaseC<int> d2 = PopulateClass<int>();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(d2.recs.First().ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(d2.recs.First().GetType().ToString());
```

prints

```
1
System.String
1
System.Int32
```

Comment: just thought I'd mention that I had to put a where T : class on the PopulateClass method declaration since in the body of the method I used T in a place where a reference type was required

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want is to make `BaseC` a generic class and specify the generic when defining the derived classes:

```
public class BaseC<T>
{
   //...
   virtual List<T> Recs { get; set; }
}

public class Derived1 : Base<MyClassA>
{
    override List<MyClassA> Recs { get; set; }
}
```

Good point by Alexei Levenkov:

> Usual note: DerivedX classes in this case will not have common parent unlike original sample. One may need to add more layer of classes (as non-generic parent of BaseC) or use an interface if DerivedX need to be treated as having common parent/interface.

Comment: +1. Usual note: `DerivedX` classes in this case will not have common parent unlike original sample. One may need to add more layer of classes (as non-generic parent of `BaseC<T>`) or use an interface if `DerivedX` need to be treated as having common parent/interface.